# Images not Loading in an Ajax Response

Tags: ajax, image

I have an AJAX call that returns HTML content with some images. Sometimes they load, but most of the time they don't.

Is there an issue I'm not aware of?

Comment: Are the image SRCs are correct all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to **[see through the ajax request](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2009/09/11/debugging-ajax-requests/)** what response are you getting. Are you getting the response from server, etc

Comment: I'm getting back content and data comes back from the server.  Through Firebug in FireFox I can actually see the image address in the html code.  Yet the image itself doesn't show up.

Comment: There should be requests from browser to server for images. Do you observe them (net tab) with firebug?

Comment: @KcYxA: Can you post what path is returned?

Comment: you're goooooood.  Figured it out :)  The image indeed was not loading as FireBug showed and I had to correct the link format.  Thank you!

Comment: @KcYxA: That is great to know :)